# Can an ansible VM in Azure query its own VM tags?

Tags: azure, ansible

I have a VM running in Azure which has ansible installed.

Is it possible to run ansible to find the tags associated with this VM (which ansible is running on)?

Furthermore Can it be done as part of a "lookup" expression?
E.g hosts: {{lookup(tag_name) }}

Comment: Are you using dynamic inventory?

Comment: Just a question why focus on Ansible in this case? You can call Azure REST APIs or use Azure Automation Accounts to do this from outside and get the results within the VM itself.

Comment: @RoadRunner: Yes I am using dynamic inventory

Comment: @HassanRaza Thank you. Your suggestion is interesting. I am not familiar with those possibilities. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we went with was to use the Ansible azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_module :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_module.html

This returns azure tag info.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating Hassan Raza's suggestion:

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) is Azure REST API reference and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags) is Tags REST API section and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/getatscope) REST API helps to get the entire set of tags on a resource. So you may just use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/getatscope) REST API to accomplish your requirement.

On the other hand, you can also leverage Az PowerShell to get the entire set of tags on a resource and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-aztag?view=azps-4.7.0) is that Az PowerShell cmdlet which is part of [Az.Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/?view=azps-4.7.0) module so you need it this module imported as a pre-requisite. Again, you may just use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-aztag?view=azps-4.7.0) cmdlet from your local machine or from wherever you want to.

On the another hand, you may also create something called [Azure Automation Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook) (in general words its a script that's created in Azure cloud under an [Azure Automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/)). So you may create an Azure Automation account and then a simple runbook to get the entire set of tags on a resource.